# VueRouter: Router push does not make an API request

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am trying to go to a route 'account/logout' and this route will make an API call.

However, this.$router.push('account/logout') is not working and it takes me to a blank page.

My guess is that the 'push' method only changes the path.

Does anyone know what method could I use to also make the API call and not just the route change?

Example:
If I enter the following route manually: https://domain/account/logout an API will be called, it will clear some cookies and it will take me to https://domain page.

If I use this.$route.push('account/logout') within Vue, it will take me to https://domain/account/logout and a blank page is shown, without having the API being called.

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Daniel_Knights sure. I added a simple example. I cannot add screenshots due to security policies. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: Without seeing more code it's impossible to tell what the issue is